# Cookie consent - Find the code that is setting the Cookies in website

Tags: javascript, cookies, cookieconsent

I am using OneTrust for my Cookie Consent.

OneTrust gives you the option to block cookies before they are set by adding this code.

```
<script type="text/plain" class="optanon-category-C0002">
// code
</script>
```

How it works:
When the above code loads, JavaScript inside the tags will not run, and no cookies will be set. Then, when the Cookie Compliance code loads, if cookies for the associated group have consent, it will dynamically change the tag to: script type=text/JavaScript

**My Problem:**
How do i find the code where the cookies are being set? (Find the file).
If i know where the cookies are set, I can add the code to block it. But i dont seem to find them.
How do you search for them?

I can see in chrome all the cookie names but not sure where they are within the website.

The website has a CMS (DNN, Evoq).

Comment: In the dev tools you can open the context menu on the cookie name and have all requests that include the cookie displayed. This will at least narrow down the search for server-side cookies (but will not be of much help with JS cookies).

Answer (score 0):

Yo

These cookie categories are standard and the defaults provided by OneTrust:

**Strictly necessary cookies ID C0001**: the website needs these cookies in order to function properly (example: identify items placed into a shopping cart)

**Performance cookies ID C0002**: get information about how site visitors are using the website (example: Google analytics)

**Functional cookies ID C0003**: provide additional enhancement of the experience of site visitors (example: language selector for localization)

**Targeting cookies ID C0004**: cookies that attempt to gather more information about a user in order to personalize marketing (example: remarketing)

**Social media cookies  ID C0005**: social media services added to the site that enable users to share content with their friends and networks easily